# The man, the weapons, the time

Tags: logical-deduction, word, story

**STORY:**

He awakes, covered in quite a thick layer of dust. Quite clearly suffering from some form of memory loss, this man begins to look around, eyes blurry, almost sticky in feeling. There's bodies around the town. The town is hot but cloudy, confusing him further. His last memory is that of America, talking to a friend called Neville. "Oh, you're nothing like the the Coroner I know." Neville took that as a compliment, assuming it was because Neville was funny, but the man knew it was clearly due to Neville's American accent.

Coming back to what seems to be the present for the moment, he feels the need to head inside a nearby building. "Mr Hyde" seems to be the only reference he can remember for your location, but that seems so unimportant for the moment, as he can barely lift his feet to walk. Where he stood now seemed a place of luxury. Where one comes to watch. There's a sign, but he can not make any sense of it, since part had been destroyed, leaving nothing but "Kino?to?en". Quite prominent, he finds the stairs leading to the front, where all eyes would see, upon which there was a note. Upon further inspection of the note, apart from it being in a format alien to him, he could make out who wrote it. A certain Doctor Edward R.

Becoming quite receptive of this almost post apocalyptic surroundings, he reaches for what he knows causes damage, and finds a weapon which needs a mechanic operating each time it's used. Inscribed on the side is L.E 303.

A slight chuckle greets him at the inscription, as it seems it's made for him. He picks the weapon up, unaware of its weight. He lurches over and mutters with frustration, "This is beneath me, I never carry mine personally."

Weapon in hand, he follows the path to a nearby exit. However, something catches his eye - a slight glisten. He turns to try and work out what his eyes are telling him. This weapon on the floor seems like the natives have made it, much like the one he holds. It is operated with a mechanic, holds 5 and seems to be the standard. Above the object, written in what is hoped to be non bodily fluid, is "penal was here". Apart from its blatant apparent absence of actual information, it seems unimportant.

In a timid manner he approaches the glowing armament and touches it. He felt catapulted. He had been shot, but he was the bullet and time was the entity landing somewhere unknown to him yet shouting "I'm Home!". It was the weapon; it was the key.

**SIDE NOTE:**

> The puzzle is to work out the missing pieces of information using your detective skills, to deduce the answers using logic and maybe a hint of help from the puzzling community. Every clue is made ensuring you do not need to be an expert programmer, physicist or mathematician. If you believe you are on the right track confirm with Google. Its your friend! I don't want the puzzle to be limited to those with higher education, therefore all the information is based upon deducing its reason for being there rather than knowing its equation, genetic make up or what it looks like in Java script.
>
> If you get an answer from other people's post it would be kind to credit them in the answer so we know who's answer for which question is most popular or considered right.
>
> Let us rather build a community on puzzling in all its aspects rather than invoking a stigma on the new guys for poor quality. If we didn't have poor quality we wouldn't have good.

**QUESTIONS:**

- What is the man's name?
- What was his job at the time?
- Where is his home?
- Who are the Penal?
- What were the 2 weapons names?
- What year in time was he taken to?
- What was the building he entered?
- What time period was this from?
- Even with the time difference, how would he know his home?

Comment: Hello, I've made a proposed edit to fix what I perceive as grammatical/formatting problems. Ex. run-on sentences, confusion between "he" and "you", change in tense from present to past, etc. If any of these things are actually intentional and important to the riddle, please don't hesitate to reject/revert them.

Comment: I have read through it and still seems on track, thank you for making the changes :)

Comment: Poor Oblong - this question still hasn't been answered! Is it worth bountying?

Comment: @randal'thor why do you have 1 reputation?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than answer the point by point questions, I'll just state that this is about:

> The [Call of Duty Black Ops "Nazi Zombies" map "Kino der Toten"](http://nazizombies.wikia.com/wiki/Kino_der_Toten) (or possibly the ["Redux" version](http://nazizombiesplus.wikia.com/wiki/Kino_Redux) which includes a character called "Neville"). The description (bodies everywhere, post-apocalyptic) fits the theme of zombies, and also matches the layout of the map, which starts inside the lobby of a movie theater ("where one comes to watch") and includes a staircase. Weapons appear in glowing outlines.

there's a sign, he could not make any sense of it, since part had been destroyed leaving nothing but "Kino?to?en"

> **Kino** der **To**t**en** is the name of the map.

a certain Doctor Edward R

> [Doctor Edward Richtofen](http://nazizombies.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Richtofen) is featured on this map.

In a timid manner he approaches the glowing armament and touches it. He felt catapulted. He had been shot, but he was the bullet and time was the entity landing somewhere unknown to him yet shouting "I'm Home!"

> There's a teleporter in this map.

There are other things to pick out from the description, but I'll leave it at that.

> The puzzle is to work out the missing pieces of information using your detective skills, to deduce the answers using logic and maybe a hint of help from the puzzling community, every clue is made ensuring you do not need to be an expert programmer, physicist or mathematician. If you believe you are on the right track confirm with google. Its your friend! I don't want the puzzle to be limited to those with higher education, therefore all the information is based upon deducing its reason for being there rather than knowing its equation, genetic make up or what it looks like in Java script.

While I support this sentiment...

> ...puzzles with answers dependent on either video game trivia or being easy to search (I've not played this and all of my information comes from the links; searching "ww2 kino" immediately yielded the answer) are no better.

Comment: Before everyone jumps on the band wagon of downvotes. This post directly answers two questions and utilises the neville clue wrongly. Also you dont say how you got the idea of it being ww2 im not going to say whether or not your answers right or wrong, but how did you know specifically to google ww2

Comment: @Oblongamous that's a fair question about why I chose to search "WW2". Initially, "Neville" (Neville Chamberlain, even though he's not American and thus can't be the right Neville), "LE 303" (Lee Enfield 303 rifle), the other magazine fed, bolt action rifle (Mauser Karabiner 98 Kurz) and talk about glowing weapons (atomic bomb) suggested WW2 to me.

Comment: Thats decent deducing there care to update your answer? It was not all about a video game I saw my sons friend bring over the night I was thinking of this scenario

Comment: Neville Chamberlain's was nicknamed The Coroner", which is why the person says this Neville is not like "the Coroner he knows" due to his accent.  This dates him to WWII.

Comment: That is correct he was nicknamed the coroner, I have asked for an answer to the questions, as I can assure you only one question is reliant on information gained from knowledge of Call of Duty